Microsoft Access running slow after Windows 11 24H2 upgrade on laptop with Intel AX211 wi-fi chipset
We're running Microsoft Access 365 with a SQL Server back-end.  Performance is generally good, but recently we've spate of complaints about the application going very slow when on wi-fi.
Having done some testing, we've narrowed it down to:
Windows 11 24H2
Dell Latitude 5540
Intel AX211 wi-fi chipset
Installing a USB wi-fi adapter resolves the issue, as does plugging in an Ethernet cable.
On another laptop, we were able to roll back the 24H2 update to 23H2 and that cures the issue too.  But you have to do that in under 10 days, or the upgrade files are removed.
I've tried multiple AX211 driver versions including 23.20.1.1, 23.60.1.2 and 23.80.0.  None of these have resolved the issue.
Has anyone else seen this issue and is there another fix other than rolling back or reinstalling 23H2?

MS has intentionally slowed some Windows aspects in the past: https://www.ghacks.net/2024/11/06/microsoft-appears-to-have-slowed-down-the-windows-control-panel-intentionally-in-the-past/ . Could that update be doing so again?

24H2 includes significant SMB and WiFi changes. Do you have WiFi 7 enabled?

@user165568 The problematic WiFi chipset is WiFi 6E.  Any idea how I would go about knocking back the standard to WiFi 5 or 6?

There have been a lot of problems with Dell/AX211 over the last couple of years. "E" just means 6 GHz band, you can change g/m/ax away from Auto if you think band selection is a problem.

@user165568, tried that, didn't work.  Next step is to try a different card such as AX201 or AX411.  AX201 because we have them elsewhere and don't seem to have the issue and AX411 to try a newer card which hopefully won't experience the same issue.

The issue appears to be with V23 of the driver package "BE200/AX411/AX211/AX210/AX201/AX200/9560/9462/9260 Wi-Fi UWD Driver", but only in Windows 11 24H2.
Installing an older V22 of the driver fixed the issue for us.
Bad versions:

23.20.1.1
23.60.1.2
23.80.0.3

Good version:

22.250.0.4, A35 (Dell)

